# Randomly select one node as the output in the neural network using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have three well-trained DNNs, and I would like to randomly select one at a time as the output of the combined model. It is something like dropout, but not exactly. How can I guarantee there is one and only one model selected?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide much information about your models and code, so I will just assume:

1. create a field of three given models that are already loaded in memory:

   ```
   model1 = ...
   model2 = ...
   model3 = ...
   models = [model1, model2, model3]
   ```

   I am not 100% sure if this is the correct way to make list of objects here, you will maybe need to [append](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-list-of-object-in-python-class/) the objects to an empty list (not tested myself).
2. randomly select one of the models:

   ```
   index = random.randint(0, 2)
   randomModel = models[index]
   ```
3. now you can use it

   ```
   randomModel.predict(givenData)
   ```

This is just rough idea, provide more details if needed further help.